# Upload contents of csv file from sftp folder to cloud SQL Server database - best practice

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to find the best way to take a csv file (20-30MB) from an sftp folder, and upload the data to a cloud based SQL Server. I'm just looking for the best approach, not looking for someone to write the code for me.

As of now I have this working (which fails 50% of the time) the following way:

1. On local PC, setup HTTPWEBREQUEST, convert file to byte array, send byte array via Stream.
2. On web server, receive stream, convert and save to temp folder on webserver.
3. Then have local PC send another message to web server that starts the following -- grab saved file on server, convert file to datatable... then execute a `SqlBulkCopy`, finally delete file on server.

This process fails half the time. I have created a new WebApi service using authentication and I would like to find the best way to do this using the new service I am creating. In my research sometimes I find information on POST a single item to the database, not sure if I should be doing something like that to 20,000 rows of data.

Can someone please point me in the right direction. Obviously what I am doing is not the best way if it keeps failing.

Comment: Could you provide the structure of the table you are saving this file to?

Comment: sure @Stivan ... its about 100 columns of data, a mix of strings/decimals/dates... do you need more information?

Comment: why is it failing? What errors / problems are you having? Is it always failing at a particular stage of the process, for instance?

Comment: honestly I can't tell, the process happens at 2am when I'm sleeping.  I figure I just want to rewrite the whole process using a new webservice I am writing in a more efficient way.  What would be the best way of going about this?

Comment: @solarissf Make sure you are storing the file into a BLOB or IMAGE

Comment: I thought BLOB was to store files, I do not want to store any files, I just want to take the data out of the csv file and save to a cloud database

Comment: @ADyson I feel like I am doing this whole process poorly since I'm downloading from ftp, then uploading file, then reading file, then deleting file

Comment: well the obvious first step would be to remove the local PC from it. Can the web server have access to the file location directly (even if it has to use ftp itself)? And once it's grabbed the file, it can kick off the database load process itself. If necessary the webserver could hand off to an asynchronous service behind the scenes to actually do this, if the web request would be too long-running. All you'd need is a way to tell the webserver to tell the service to run

Comment: I don't see why not.  The webservice can log in to a ftp folder same as any other c# project I write, correct?  But when you say grab the file, that's my question, do I download the file and save on the webservice somewhere, or can I skip that step?

Comment: @Adyson, does the webservice HAVE to download the file from ftp and save locally before using, or is there a way to access file on ftp site without saving locally?

Comment: @solarissf well you could, but effectively by accessing it and streaming it, you're basically downloading it anyway (moving data from one machine to another is a download of sorts, however you dress it up). If you do, you run a slightly higher risk of failure if your connection drops while you're processing the file - probably harder to recover from than if you grab the whole file onto the local webserver before you start processing it. Or can you cut out the FTP entirely and have users upload directly to the webservice?